# separate comma and line in foreach

Tags: c#, string

If its possible I want to separate comma and line in `foreach`. 20 is npc's id, 10 is amount of npc, and comma means this npc. Thanks for any help :)

```
string npcs = " 20 - 10 , 30 - 40 "; 
//or
string[] npcs = {" 20 - 10 ", " 30 - 40 "};
```

Comment: What should be your output looks like? Can you give an example?

Comment: id = 20 , amount = 10.
id = 30 , amount = 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question properly, but I believe you want to retrieve your NPCs information from a single string. If so, here's my solution:

```
string npcs = " 20 - 10 , 30 - 40 ";

foreach (var npc in npcs.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var npcInfo = npc.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string npcID = npcInfo[0];
    string npcAmount = npcInfo[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose like this:

```
string npcs = " 20 - 10 , 30 - 40 ";

//All IDs like 20,30
var ids = npcs.Split(',').Select(c => c.Split('-').First());

//All amounts like 10,40
var amounts = npcs.Split(',').Select(c => c.Split('-').Last());
```